# How is interest rate calculated for a floating mortgage

Tags: mortgage, interest

I am trying to calculate the amount of interest I need to pay for a mortgage that just turned from fixed to floating.

- Current balance is: -550,000
- Interest rate: 5.95%
- Original term: 30 years

The monthly interest is calculated as:

- 550000*0.0595/12 = 2727.08333

The fortnightly interest is calculated as:

- 2727.08333/2 = 1363.54

Was I correct?

Comment: Looks fine, but there are 26 fortnights in a year, not 24.

Comment: @HartCO, thanks for pointing it out. My assumption was wrong.

Comment: So yours was semi-monthly rather than bi-weekly, both are somewhat common alternatives to monthly mortgage payments.

Comment: You will save a lot of money if you convert that to a conventional mortgage, unless you have really poor credit scores.

Comment: @Norm, conventional mortgage? Did you mean fixed mortgage.

Comment: Yes, fixed rate conventional, you should be able to get that rate down below 4% with halfway decent credit scores.